# R: extracting data from password secured site

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data from a password secured site thru R. I have tried many options. But I am getting only the HTML of non-login page even after passing login credentials. Here is one of my attempts:

```
loginurl ="https://login.recruit.naukri.com/"
dataurl  = "http://resdex.naukri.com/search/setSrchSess?     SRCHTYPE=ez&SRCH_INC_KEYWORD=XXX"
pars=list(username="XXX", password="XXX")
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar="",  useragent = agent, followlocation = TRUE,  curl=curl)
html=postForm(loginurl, .params = pars, curl=curl)
html=getURL(dataurl, curl=curl)
```

Both htmls are same and they are HTML of non-login page.

The same is happening with others commands also.

Comment: You have only one html, the second call overwrite the value in the `html` var... Then I don't know how you secure site works, but if it tries to set a cookie to store the auth state, you'll have to store it and send it in the second query.

Comment: I used different variables say html1 and html2, both are same. According to you, I don't need to send cookie in first query. When I enter the login details in site, page changes. But var html1 only returns the page source of non-login site.